# Calling an Oracle stored procedure in Squirrel SQL

Tags: java, oracle, squirrel-sql

I was able to create a stored procedure for an Oracle database, but now I can't figure out how to run it. I'm using SQuirrel SQL and this worked to create the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProc(label IN varchar2, results OUT sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
OPEN results FOR
    SELECT Label, Count, Timestamp 
        FROM table1
            LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Name=table2.Name 
    WHERE table1.Label=label
    ORDER BY Timestamp;
END;
/
```

I want to be able to get and display the result set. I've tried using `call MyProc('param')`, but this doesn't work (wrong number of arguments error). I've searched extensively on this site and others but nothing has been useful. Please help!

Comment: @dovka's answer appears to be the only one which answers the question. Kayeight wasn't asking how to call procedures from Squirrel. The question's current title, "Calling an Oracle stored procedure in Squirrel SQL", is misleading.

Answer (score 18):

The following works to run a stored procedure:

```
begin
   procedurename;
end;
/
```

Yes, **the slash at the end** is necessary!

The `begin...end;` declares a *PL/SQL block* (Oracle-specific). The slash is the command to run the block.

> /(slash)
>
> Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which
>   is stored in the SQL buffer.
>
> [...]

[Oracle Database Online Documentation, 10g Release 2 (10.2) / SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm)

Comment: How does this answer the question? @Kayeight's stored procedure has two parameters: one in, and one out. So how does one call a stored procedure with an 'out' parameter, via Squirrel SQL? If the `begin procedurename; end; /` syntax is superior to `call procedurename;`, please explain why.

Comment: _..is necessary.._ as are the 2 rather than 3 semicolons!

Answer (score 4):

The only syntax I get working in Squirrel SQL is **PL/SQL block:**

```
declare
v_label  varchar2:='SOMELABEL';
TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
v_cur_results ref_cursor;
begin
MyProc (v_label, v_cur_results)
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [this article](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-tools/128624-how-execute-oracle-stored-procedures-within-squirrel-sql.html) explains, using "call" instead of "execute" should solve the problem.

Comment: Read the question again--the questioner already knew about `call`.

Comment: The link to the article is dead

Answer (score 0):

```
var v_result sys_refcursor

exec MyProc ('test label',:v_result)
```

Comment: I don't have SQL*Plus, I'm using Squirrel SQL, so this does not work. :(

Comment: This syntax is Oracle specific. Have you installed Oracle plugin in SQL Squirrel ?  http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins

Comment: It says the plugin is installed, but I get a ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error...

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this for a long time but have managed to make it work like this :

```
{call DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT  ( namespace => 'clientcontext', attribute => 'foo', value     => 'bar' )}
```